# Increase Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection Attempts

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm trying to increase the number of connection retries after RDP looses an established connection. I found [this solution](https://itsiti.com/increase-windows-remote-desktop-connection-attempts/), telling me to add `AutoReconnect Max Retries:i:xx` to the default.rdp file. So far I couldn't get it to work. I noticed it's not listed in the [MS reference for RDP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files). I tried different values with the parameter, e.g. `AutoReconnect Max Retries:i:50`.

Adding the line to default.rdp "breaks" `mstsc.exe` in a way that it won't connect to any machines any more (nothing happens after hitting the "connect"-Button).

Adding the line to another rdp-file configured to connect to a specific computer it results in an error message that no connection can be established to the remote computer (the connection worked fine before adding the new parameter line).

Did anyone get the solution still work with Windows 10 or is there a different working solution for Windows 10?

Comment: Do you have in the `.rdp` file the line `autoreconnection enabled:i:1`? Does it disconnect because it was idle for too long?

Comment: and did you replace the xx with the amount you want to use? eg `AutoReconnect Max Retries:i:99`

Comment: @LPChip yes, I tried different values e.g. `AutoReconnect Max Retries:i:50`

Comment: @harrymc yes, I got autoreconnection enabled, after a disconnect (various reasons), it tries the 20 default reconnections attempts and then gives up. I want it to try more then the 20 default reconnect attempts.

Comment: In theory this should work: `AutoReconnect Max Retries:i:1000`.

Comment: @harrymc I tried and it doesn't (see question for further info)

Comment: Actually the Max Retries limit is apparently 200. Are you using the built-in RDP or the Microsoft Remote Desktop from the Microsoft Store? Try running [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I'm using the build-in RDP, "sfc /scannow" didn't help, what was it suppose to do in this case?

Comment: @harrymc did you try it yourself? Which Windows version?